# Circle Ci 2.0 artifacts url

Tags: circleci, artifacts

Circle Ci 2.0 artifacts can be accessed with the following url

`https://{BUILD_NUMBER}-{UNKNOWN_NUMBER}-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0`

What does the number after CI build number represent.

Answer (score 8):

If, like me, you were looking for a way to programmatically reference CircleCI (2.0) artifacts, the following url structure works for me:

```
https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/:vcs-type/:username/:project/:build_num/artifacts/0/:path-to-artifact?circle-token=:token&branch=:branch
```

For example:

https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/circleci/circleci-docs/latest/artifacts/0/run-results/build-results.txt?branch=realitycheck&filter=successful

resolves to the `build-results.txt` artifact on the latest, successful build of  the circleci-docs project's realitycheck branch.

Constructing the `:path-to-artifact` can be done by inspecting your CircleCI artifacts directory structure:

[image]

From the above, the `:path-to-artifact` is `0/run-results/build-results.txt`.

Reference:

- https://circleci.com/docs/api/v1-reference/#build-artifacts

Comment: On the other hand, if you really just wanted to know what `{UNKNOWN_NUMBER}` is, I have no idea. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There are also Bitbucket repos. So {UNKNOWN_NUMBER} dont't have to be a Github repo id as stated in answer below. Pretty sure CircleCI has an environment variable for it. And I would also like to know it :)

Comment: I ended up getting a permission error if I included the token so I used `https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/:vcs-type/:username/:project/:build_num/artifacts/0/:path-to-artifact?circle-token=:token&branch=:branch` and it worked beautifully!

Comment: The only that works for me is `wget` and a different URL. Also, i was mistaken in my understanding of what an artifacts is because after 30 days it is deleted!? So, how can I use it in my other builds then?!?

Answer (score 2):

The `{UNKNOWN_NUMBER}` represents the Github id of the repository.

If you run the snippet below you can get the id you want for any organisation and repository as provided by the [github rest API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)

```js
function query_gh(){
  var org = document.getElementById("org").value;
  var repo = document.getElementById("repo").value;

  async function query(org, repo) {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.github.com/orgs/"+org+"/repos");
    const outJson = await response.json();

    for (var i = 0; i < outJson.length; i++){
      var repository = outJson[i];
      if (repository.name == repo) {
        id = repository.id;
        output.innerHTML = org +"/"+ repo + " has ID: " + id;
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  query(org, repo);
  return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Enter names of the GH organisation and repository</p>
<form onsubmit="query_gh(); return false;">
 <label for="org">Organisation</label>
 <input type="text" id="org" required="">
 <br>
 <label for="repo">Repository</label>
 <input type="text" id="repo" required="">
 <br>
 <button type="submit">Query</button>

</form>

<div id="output">
 <span id="output_text">...</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What in case of a Bitbucket repo?

Comment: With Bitbucket is the same but with the url as: `https://{BUILD_NUMBER}-{BB-id}-bb.circle-artifacts.com/`. You can print what's that URL with the `${CIRCLE_BUILD_URL}` variable. To get that id for a BB repository go to: `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/` and look for: `uuid`. Look at the [bitbucket API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D#post) for more details.